# Insertar un combobox con el boton subir archivos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Hola buenas tardes tengo un codigo que uso para subir archivos pero necesito que no solo suba archivos si no que tambien me suba el combobox porque la imagen va segun la seleccion del combobox alguien me podria ayudar tengo dos campos image y image_text (image que es donde va la imagen y image_text ese campo lo tengo vacio porque no se como insertarlo aca muestro el codigo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el html

```
<h3>EVIDENCIA POR CATEGORIA </h3>
    <!-- Inicia cargue fotos  -->

     <label class="control-label">Cargue archivo evidencias:</label>
      <input name="archivo" type="file" id="imagen" /><br /><br />

       <select  class="form-control"  id="image_text">

                   <option value="placa grua">Regla de Oro - Linea Desenergizada</option>
                   <option value="placa canasta">Procedimientos de Trabajo</option>
                   <option value="placa moto">Elementos de Proteccion Personal</option>
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Materiales, Equipos y herramientas.</option>    
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Condiciones de Trabajo</option>   
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Señalizacion y proteccion publica</option>      
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Identificacion de Riesgo / Charla Pre-operacional</option>      
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Identificacion y competencia personal</option>      
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Vehiculos (Pesado,liviano y motos) y maquinaria</option>      
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Primeros Auxilios y Emergencias</option>      
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Regla de oro Linea Energizada</option>      
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Desplazamiento a pie</option>      
                   <option value="placa vehiculo">Espacios confinados (Subestaciones de sotanos, camaras y otros)</option>   

                  </select>
          <input type="button" value="Subir imagen" id="cargueArchivo" />
        <!--div para visualizar mensajes-->
      <div class="messages"></div><br /><br />
      <!--div para visualizar en el caso de imagen-->
      <div class="showImage">
```

este es el php

```
<?php
session_start();
include "conectar.php";
$link = conectar();

//comprobamos que sea una petición ajax
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{

    //obtenemos el archivo a subir

    $file = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

    //comprobamos si existe un directorio para subir el archivo
    //si no es así, lo creamos
    if(!is_dir("../files/"))
        mkdir("../files/", 0777);

    //comprobamos si el archivo ha subido
    if ($file && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],"../files/".$file))
    {
        sleep(3);//retrasamos la petición 3 segundos
        echo $file;//devolvemos el nombre del archivo para pintar la imagen
        //Insertar BD


            $image =  $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            // Get text
            //$image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);

            //$sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text, id_inspeccion) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text','". $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] ."')";
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text, id_inspeccion) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text','". $_SESSION['id_inspeccion'] ."')";
            $result = $link->query($sql);
            // execute query
            //mysqli_query($db, $sql);

       //Fin.Insertar BD
    }
}else{
    throw new Exception("Error Processing Request", 1);
}
?>
```

y este es mi ajax

```
//funcion cargueArchivo
    $(':file').change(function()
     {
         //obtenemos un array con los datos del archivo
         var file = $("#imagen")[0].files[0];
         //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
         var fileName = file.name;
         //obtenemos la extensión del archivo
         fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
         //obtenemos el tamaño del archivo
         var fileSize = file.size;
         //obtenemos el tipo de archivo image/png ejemplo
         var fileType = file.type;
         //mensaje con la información del archivo
         showMessage("<span class='info'>Archivo para subir: "+fileName+", peso total: "+fileSize+" bytes.</span>");
     });




    $('#cargueArchivo').click(function(){
        //información del formulario
        var formData = new FormData($("#frmFormulario")[0]);

        var message = "";
        //hacemos la petición ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/upload.php',
            type: 'POST',
            // Form data
            //datos del formulario
            data: formData,
            //necesario para subir archivos via ajax
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            //mientras enviamos el archivo
            beforeSend: function(){
                message = $("<span class='before'>Subiendo la imagen, por favor espere...</span>");
                showMessage(message);
            },
            //una vez finalizado correctamente
            success: function(data){
                message = $("<span class='success'>La imagen ha subido correctamente.</span>");
                showMessage(message);
                if(isImage(fileExtension))
                {
                    //$(".showImage").html("Imagen Cargada: <img height ='500' src='/../files/"+data+"' />");


                    //alert('Se ha guardado correctamente el registro: ' + data);
                    $.post('php/imagen_actualiza.php', data, function(data2, textStatus, xhr) {
                        //alert('Data2: ' + data2);
                        $(".showImage").html(data2);

                    });
                    return;

                                        //showMessage("");
                                        //$('#cargueArchivo').prop('disabled',false);
                                        //$(':files').prop('disabled',false);

                }
            },
            //si ha ocurrido un error
            error: function(){
                message = $("<span class='error'>Ha ocurrido un error.</span>");
                showMessage(message);
            }
        });
    });
    //FIN funcion cargueArchivo
    //funcion incumplimiento
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar mas parametros al `var formData = new FormData($("#frmFormulario")[0]);`

de la siguiente manera:

```
var nombre =$("#image_text").val();
formData.append("image_text",nombre);
```

> Cuando tenemos un objeto FormData disponemos en él de un método append() que nos permite agregar ese par llave/valor. Los datos que podemos agregar pueden provenir de formularios que ya tengamos creados, pero también de cualquier otra fuente, recurso o servicio que dispongamos en Javascript. Este método append() recibe varios parámetros, de momento indicaremos como primer parámetro el nombre del dato y como segundo el valor.

El resultado es el esperado :

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image_text"
placa grua
```

y lo puedes utilizar en tu archivo php mediante `$_POST['image_text']`